# Strategies for downloading a query result in django

Tags: python, django

I have a page in django, where I query a database. I want to download the result as a csv- but as I know, it is not possible to add two buttons/functions for one page. 
My solution would be that I add a link to a new page or new window, where I show the result table again and put the button there, but first I would like to ask if there is a more elegant way to do it?

view.py

```
def FilterView(request):
    if title_exact_query != '' and title_exact_query is not None:
        qs = ExperimentFiles.objects.filter(Q(donor_id=title_exact_query)).values().order_by(
            'record_name__date_of_measurement')
        context = {
                'queryset': qs,
        }
        return render(request, "search.html", context)
```

serach.html:

```
    <form method="GET" action=".">

      <input class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border" type="search" name="id_exact" placeholder="donor ID" /><br>

            <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="donor_id" name="donor_id" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="donor_id">
              ID
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="name" name="name" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="name">
              Name
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="age" name="age" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="age">
              Age
            </label>
          </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a POST request when you want to download the csv so that you could easily use the same view by implementing an if statement on the method of the request.

```
def FilterView(request):
    if title_exact_query != '' and title_exact_query is not None:
        qs = ExperimentFiles.objects.filter(Q(donor_id=title_exact_query)).values().order_by(
            'record_name__date_of_measurement')
        if request.method =="POST":
           
            csv = to_csv(qs)  #function for csv creation
            response = HttpResponse(csv, content_type='text/csv')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=stockitems_misuper.csv'
            return response 
           
        context = {
                'queryset': qs,
        }
        return render(request, "search.html", context)
```